# Best way to prevent error carried forward?

Tags: c#, floating-point, fixed-point

I have a large data array created by sampling a voltage at 250 kHz. I would like to print the data along with the associated time to a file. My first approach would be to do it like this (in C#):

```
decimal dt = 1m / sampleRate;
decimal t = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
{
    Writer.WriteLine(t + "\t" + dataArray[i]);

    t += dt;  //Would using t = i * dt; be any different?
}
```

Obviously due to the inherent nature of <strike>floating point math</strike> this approach, it starts to accumulate an error that becomes significant after several seconds of data.

My approach to solve this problem would be something like this:

```
decimal dt = (decimal)(1 / sampleRate);
decimal t = 0;
int seconds = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
{
    if(i % sampleRate == 0)
        {
            t = seconds;
            seconds++;
        }
    Writer.WriteLine(t + "\t" + dataArray[i]);

    t += dt;  
}
```

Which keeps everything synced up well enough but doesn't seem particularly elegant. Is there a better way to approach this? And finally, in the top approach, is using t += dt any different from t = i * dt with a decimal? What about with a double?

EDIT: As has been pointed out, decimal is not floating point. Should I be using decimal or double here?

Comment: What type is sampleRate?

Comment: sampleRate is an integer, in this case 250000.

Comment: Calculate the rate at the end.

Comment: I would not use a floating point type for t.  Use an integer type, and then t is just "sample number".  Then you can write a function that converts a given sample number to a floating point value in seconds based on sample rate.  Then you have no error accumulation, and you have full access to the exact time in sample number.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `decimal`, you are *not* doing floating-point math.  `decimal` is basically a fixed-point number.

Comment: I was under the impression that decimal was just more precise than double? I probably should have checked that.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `decimal`, which is fixed point. You shouldn't have any error (unless, of course, your values are out of the supported range of `decimal`).

Your first statement, though, is incorrect. You are doing integer math (with will result in an integer result) and then casting to a decimal. You need to do things a bit different to force the calculation properly:

```
decimal dt = 1m / sampleRate;
```

Comment: You probably meant `decimal dt ...`

Comment: @SumuduFernando - That's exactly what I meant! Fixed. Too much thinking about double vs. decimal. Doh!

Comment: Oops, the actual code I'm using is slightly different. I didn't even realize I had screwed that up here. I've edited the question to fix that.